# How to use session_start() just in the first class, and not in inheritance object

Tags: php, oop

I have problem here, this is the example code:

```
class example {
   public function  __construct() {
      session_start();
      echo "this is from example class";
   }
}

class example2 extends example {
   public function __construct(){
      echo "this is form example2 class";
   }
}

$example = new example(); // until here, no error.
// Output: this is form example class

$example2 = new example2() // here, I get error
// Output: this is form example class
// Output: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
// Output: this is from example2 class
```

So, how to fix this? How to ignoring session_start() in the example class, so in the example2 class, the session_start() is not running again.

Comment: You could either define the start of the session in a Utility class, or check if a session exists by using `if (isset($_SESSION['a_var_registered_to_your_sess'])) ...`. For more info, please see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-is-registered.php#refsect1-function.session-is-registered-notes

Comment: If the purpose of your class is not to manage the session then **it is not** the appropriate place for any `session_*` function. Read about [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to call `parent::__construct()` like that in the second class.

```
    class example {
   public function  __construct() {
      if(!isset($_SESSION)){
          session_start();
      }
      echo "this is from example class";
   }
}

class example2 extends example {
   public function __construct(){
      parent::__construct(); // add this line
      echo "this is form example2 class";
   }
}

$example = new example(); // until here, no error.
// Output: this is form example class

$example2 = new example2() // here, I get error
// Output: this is form example class
// Output: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
// Output: this is from example2 class
```

Comment: error: Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Comment: Edited. See first class.